# RatingBar stars shows weird effect

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

I am using rating bar to show movie rating in my app. Placed rating bar like this in my layout file:

```
               <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/RatingBar"
                style="@style/MicRatingBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/movie_img"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="3.0"
                android:stepSize="1"
                android:textColor="@drawable/button_text" />
```

In the style part, I've assigned it minHeight and maxHeight 9dp which reduce the weird but not completely gone. My rating bar look like this. what is these lines. please help. thanks in advance.

[image]

The style part is this:

```
<style name="MicRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_rating_selector</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">9dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">9dip</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: This isn't the emulator, so it's not an accurate representation of how the rating bar looks in effect. Please show us that, and also - show us the style/MicRatingBar

Comment: same effect on emulator. style xml is updated

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into [minHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:minHeight) for a View class and [maxHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:maxHeight) of ProgressBar (no maxHeight attribute in View class). When you set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, it tries to measure itself to the minimum height you have provided. You could get wider idea if you see `onMeasure(...)` of AbsSeekBar (RatingBar extends AbsSeekBar)